# SQL code to call all the columns from a Tb expect one column which can be called using As?

Tags: mysql, sql

My current code is given below. I wanted to call all the columns from the table using * but the idcastncrew column name should display like castncrewid. In the requirement code, it's not working though, I wish there was a solution for my requirement such as the sample Requirement code.

Current code:-

```
SELECT idcastncrew AS castncrewid,castncrewname,castncrewtype,castncrewrole,imagelink,vendor,mode FROM subscriber;
```

Requirement :-

```
SELECT idcastncrew AS castncrewid, * FROM subscriber;
```

Comment: not possible. You need to specify the columns you want and any alias in your list of columns.

Comment: Either asperisk or all columns one-by-one. And asterisk not in the beginning of the output list is not allowed in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I think you can get is to have the renamed column twice, once with the new name and once with the old name.

While MySQL does ***not*** allow `*` after an aliased column *(causing your second code snippet to give an error)*, it does allow `table.*` anywhere...

```
SELECT idcastncrew AS castncrewid, subscriber.*  
FROM subscriber;
```

To re-iterate; you'll still get a `idcastncrew` column, but you will ALSO get a `castncrewid` column.

There is no way to say `don't include *this* column` when using `*` in MySQL

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c69c537e46ad29e3c0c8c03d3ebd1bf7

Answer (score 1):

You can alias columns when you alias the table, example as follows

```
MariaDB [DEV]> create table xxx (id int, str varchar(20));
MariaDB [DEV]> insert into xxx values (1, 'hi');
MariaDB [DEV]> insert into xxx values (2, 'Hello');
MariaDB [DEV]> insert into xxx values (3, 'World');
MariaDB [DEV]> insert into xxx values (4, 'Goodbye');

MariaDB [DEV]> select a.id as id1, a.* from xxx a order by 1;
+------+------+---------+
| id1  | id   | str     |
+------+------+---------+
|    1 |    1 | hi      |
|    2 |    2 | Hello   |
|    3 |    3 | World   |
|    4 |    4 | Goodbye |
+------+------+---------+
```